# I can't run eclipse IDE installer

Tags: java, ide

From system variables part, I made one for JAVA_HOME and now I got the same version for both java and javac. 
Yet, the IDE installers says that it cannot find java needed to run the installer. Showing the page saying "JAVA missing". 
I added images for them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you installed eclipse 64bit or 32 bit version?

Comment: I don't think I downloaded 32 bit version.

Comment: Just confirm that Eclipse and Java are the same version, I mean both 32 or both 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Were you getting response in command prompt similar to below?

```
C:\Users\Ramu>java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

C:\Users\Ramu>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_60

C:\Users\Ramu>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

Please note you may have to reboot your system for environment variables to propagate if you just added environment variable.

Comment: I get versions for java and javac as the pictures on the post (someone nice edited it.) 
and about ECHO. I get ; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2 
And I rebooted my laptop and it still says the same thing; java missing